# Implementing Search in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, solr, sitecore, glass-mapper

I have been doing research on how to implement search in my website. It looks like Sitecore is recommending Solr over Lucene based on this [article](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/using_solr_or_lucene). I'm also using Glass.Mapper as the ORM and have seen this [article](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial25), but am still not exactly sure on how to implement it. Does anyone know of a good tutorial on getting started with search in a Sitecore 8.1 website?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions like this will getter better answers on the Sitecore community site.. you might consider registering there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supported, but did not implement a Sitecore 8/Solr implementation until about a year ago. This is a big subject you are asking about.

I would suggest doing additional research before ruling out Lucene. It's too big a decision to be left to Sitecore's little article. You'll want to make sure you can get the support you need, and the culture is very different between Lucene and Solr. Be aware [Solr is built on Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

To evaluate Solr, start with their [basic tutorials](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/resources.html#tutorials). (The Sitecore + Solr articles assume a passing familiarity with both products.)

Here are **tutorials for building Solr with Sitecore 8**:

http://thinking.edynamic.net/making-solr-search-work-with-sitecore-8-part-1

https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/search/solr/Configuring-Solr-for-use-with-Sitecore-8/

Definitely read what Sitecore's docs say. [This article](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/configure_a_search_and_indexing_provider) covers setup of Lucene and Solr in one doc (and may be useful for comparison).

Finally, be sure to register on [Sitecore Developer Network](https://sdn.sitecore.net/).

Comment: The Sitecore Developer Network does not cover Sitecore 8.1...

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @Gatogordo, are you saying that because the documentation says 8.0, or for a more specific reason? Sitecore often doesn't update documentation for dot-releases, unless relevant changes were made to that functionality. Consider their training courses: http://www.sitecore.net/services-and-support/training/classroom-training/back-end-developers.aspx